# postgres / sql self join comparing rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have the following example table

```
id, label, reason, timestamp
7, 123, ok, 10:50:01
6, 124, reject, 10:53:01
5, 123, reject, 10:30:02
4, 124, ok, 10:30:01
```

I'd like to get the rows whereby the if the label's last record (latest timestamp) is an ok we display it in the results but if there was a reject we don't.

e.g.

```
7, 123, ok, 10:50:01
```

It should be simple but I'm really having issues. Can someone assist ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest `distinct on`:

```
select t.*
from (select distinct on (label) t.*
      from t
      order by label, timestamp desc
     ) t
where reason = 'ok';
```

You can also do this as:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.timestamp = (select max(t2.timestamp)
                     from t t2
                     where t2.label = t.label
                    ) and
      t.reason = 'ok';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your query.

```
select t1.* from 
  (select row_number() over (order by timestamp desc) as rn
       , id, label, reason, timestamp
   from tableA) as t1 
where t1.rn = 1 and t1.reason = 'ok'
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use some exists logic here:

```
SELECT id, label, reason, timestamp
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE
    reason = 'ok' AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
                WHERE t2.label = t1.label AND
                      t2.timestamp > t1.timestamp);
```

This assumes you want the matching single *row* with the latest timestamp.